# Problems with PayPal Sandbox API: SSL, CORS, and CORB errors

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, cross-origin-read-blocking

I've been developing an application that uses PayPal, and as of about a month or so ago it was connecting to their Sandbox API and I could see valid API calls on their "Sandbox API Call History" page.

Now, when I visit the "API Calls" page, I'm seeing:

> Something went wrong fetching sandbox API calls. Try again. If you
>   wish to report this error please include the following error id: XXXX.

... with no API calls, and on the payment page within the application, I'm seeing this in the Developer Console for Google Chrome:

> The SSL certificate used to load resources from
>   https://www.sandbox.paypal.com will be distrusted in M70. Once
>   distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See
>   https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.
>
> Failed to load
>   https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-3PW18164HS5387942:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://5-towns' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-3PW18164HS5387942
>   with MIME type text/html. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

As I understand it, the SSL certificate issue appears to be negligence on the part of PayPal, but the other issues, and the whole range of issues in general are overwhelming; I'm new to using the PayPal API and I don't know where to begin.